# Multiple signals requires multiple filters?

Tags: signal-processing

So, this might seem rather basic, but I'm going to pose it in the hope that I can save some work. So, I have a series of electrodes that are sensitive to voltage fluctuations, but, before I pass the data into the Arduino and then into the computer, I wanted to create a circuit that acts as a bandpass filter in order to reduce 60hz noise from appliances as well as to limit the read frequencies.

Though, I plan on using a good number of electrodes (either 16 or 32 as of right now) so, rather than running each individual electrode through a separate bandpass filter, is it possible to apply these filters by passing multiple electrode signals through a single or a smaller number of filters rather than having to build one filter for every input? Thanks in advance for any insight you guys can provide.

Comment: Can you pour 16 different fluids through a Britta water filter and have them all separate at the end of it? No.

Comment: What frequencies do you WANT to sample? DC or frequencies up to? Down to?

Comment: This question is how to create a bandpass filter *before* passing data to the Arduino, so I think the Electronics Stack Exchange is better suited to answering this. I'll migrate it for you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible way you could to that is through a technique called *Time Division Multiplexing*.

This involves you having a set of analog switches to select one of your incoming signals at a time for filtering. You can only read one signal at a time, and each one for a period longer than you need for the filtering to have any effect.

Also this would probably increase your noise in your signal in the first place.

Comment: “Only possible way” ?  I doubt it.  Perhaps the easiest, however.

Comment: Come up with another way then. Go on, I challenge you.

Comment: [16qam](http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/rf-technology-design/quadrature-amplitude-modulation-qam/8qam-16qam-32qam-64qam-128qam-256qam.php) can do it – but 16 separate filters would be a lot easier, and I suggest that explaining why separate filters will involve less messing around is what your answer should have, rather than suggesting TDM

Comment: @jwpat7 I don't see what that has to do with anything...

Comment: @jwpat7 I rather think that QAM is a little beyond the average Arduino user. If they have to ask this question then QAM is not going to be a feasible option for them.